# Ubuntu Welcome Screen Returns After Install

Tags: installation, usb

I am a brand new Ubuntu user. I recently made the switch by creating a USB Boot Drive with PenDrive. I followed the online instructions to have computer boot from the USB. Initially, I chose the 'Try Ubuntu' option. I liked what I saw, so I chose to 'Install Ubuntu".

My problem is this: I believe I had followed the 'Install Ubuntu' instructions to a tee; however, after I am prompted to restart my computer after installation, I am brought back to the Ubuntu Welcome screen with the option to "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu". The bloody Welcome Screen keeps coming back!

My apologies if this has been answered in another forum.

Comment: Did you remove the USB drive or change back the boot order to hard drive in BIOS?

Comment: I edited your post to remove your second question, since each question should deal with just one topic. Feel free to post another question if you have another specific need.